# Qt c++ Linux QWebView VideoCapture

Tags: c++, qt, html5-video, video-capture

I'm try to make navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia in my Qt project with QWebView. In html I use standard code which work fine:

```
<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
    
    </video>
</div>

<script>

var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

</script>
```

When I open it in browser, it get access to webcam and display video. But when I run in Qt I get error in console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')
```

please help: how to set access for video in QWebView? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to request one of the permissions to use video & audio `QWebEnginePage::setFeaturePermission(const QUrl &securityOrigin, QWebEnginePage::MediaAudioVideoCapture) ` .check this [QWebEnginePage::Feature](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#Feature-enum)  for more features.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to request one of the ***permissions*** to use **video & audio**

```
QWebEnginePage::setFeaturePermission(const QUrl &securityOrigin,  QWebEnginePage::Feature feature, QWebEnginePage::PermissionPolicy policy)
```

Check this [QWebEnginePage::Feature](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#Feature-enum) & this [QWebEnginePage::PermissionPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#PermissionPolicy-enum) for more information.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I use QWebView by Raspberry pi and it not have QWebEnginePage